# Why is unsafe Unsafe_Shutdown_Count increases on every shutdown?

Tags: ssd, shutdown, storage, smart

This SMART attribute seems to increase on every shutdown even if I seem to shut down normally. Why is this and how do you fix it so that it shuts down safely?

This is Xubuntu 20.04 machine with an SSD storage.

Related [question](https://superuser.com/q/1745794/490855)

Comment: SMART attributes descriptions are not always accurate for all devices. If everything works OK, there is no reason to worry.